# Error converting data type varchar to numeric and varchar to datetime

Tags: sql-server-2005

Error converting data type varchar to numeric

The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

```
declare @rsnMain numeric, @rsnAcnt numeric, @rsnRel numeric;
set @rsnMain = (select max(record_serial_number)
                from sdg_aaismain)
set @rsnAcnt = (select max(record_serial_number)
                from sdg_aaisacnt)
set @rsnRel = (select max(record_serial_number)
                from sdg_aaisrel)

insert into sdg_aaismain
(RECORD_SERIAL_NUMBER,
 AGENT_NUMBER,
 AGENT_STATUS_CODE,
 AGENT_STATUS_DESP,
 TRADE_NAME,
 GROUP_TYPE_1,
 MADE_ON_BEHALF,
 MADE_ON_BEHALF_DESP,
 LICENSE_RENEWAL_CODE,
 LICENSE_RENEW_DESP,
 ACTUAL_NO_STREET,
 ACTUAL_TOWN,
 ACTUAL_STATE,
 ZIP_CODE_PREFIX,
 ZIP_CODE_SUFFIX,
 CITY_CODE,
 DISTRICT_CODE,
 COUNTY_CODE,
 MUNICIPALITY_CODE,
 ACTUAL_DISTRICT,
 ACTUAL_COUNTY,
 ACTUAL_MUNICIPALITY,
 CONTACT_LAST_NAME,
 CONTACT_FIRST_NAME,
 STORE_OPEN_HOURS#1,
 STORE_OPEN_HOURS#2,
 STORE_OPEN_HOURS#3,
 STORE_OPEN_HOURS#4,
 STORE_OPEN_HOURS#5,
 STORE_OPEN_HOURS#6,
 STORE_OPEN_HOURS#7,
 STORE_CLOSE_HOURS#1,
 STORE_CLOSE_HOURS#2,
 STORE_CLOSE_HOURS#3,
 STORE_CLOSE_HOURS#4,
 STORE_CLOSE_HOURS#5,
 STORE_CLOSE_HOURS#6,
 STORE_CLOSE_HOURS#7,
 MAILING_ADDRESS,
 MAILING_CITY,
 MAILING_STATE,
 MAILING_ZIP_CODE_PREFIX,
 MAILING_ZIP_CODE_SUFFIX,
 CREATE_DATE,
 MODIFY_DATE,
 MODIFY_TIME,
 USER_ID,
 AGENT_TYPE,
 NAIC_CODE,
 CONTRACT_TYPE,
 LONGITUDE,
 LATITUDE,
 CORP_NAME,
 DSR,
 FEDTAX_NAME,
 FEDTAX_ID,
 TIN_TYPE,
 NAME_CNTL,
 ES_GROUPTYPE,
 ADDRESS2,
 --CORPORATION_NUMBER)
INSTALL_DATE)

select 
 @rsnMain + ROW_NUMBER() over (order by agent_number),
 AGENT_NUMBER,
 AGENT_STATUS_CODE,
 AGENT_STATUS_DESC,
 TRADE_NAME, 
 cast(right(CHAIN_PARENT_RETAIL_NO,3) as numeric(3,0)) as GROUP_TYPE_1,
 MADE_ON_BEHALF,
 MOB_DESC,
 LICENSE_RENEWAL_CODE,
 RENEWAL_STATUS_DESC,
 ACTUAL_NO_STREET,
 ACTUAL_TOWN, ACTUAL_STATE,
 cast(ZIP_PREFIX as numeric (5,0)) as ZIP_PREFIX,
 cast(ZIP_SUFFIX as numeric (4,0)) as ZIP_SUFFIX,
 CITY_CODE,
 cast(DISTRICT_CODE as numeric (3,0)) as DISTRICT_CODE,
 cast(COUNTY_CODE as numeric(3,0)) as COUNTY_CODE,
 MUNICIPALITY_CODE,
 ACTUAL_DISTRICT,
 ACTUAL_COUNTY,
 ACTUAL_MUNICIPALITY,
 CONTACT_LAST_NAME,
 CONTACT_FIRST_NAME,
 STORE_OPEN_HOURS#1,
 STORE_OPEN_HOURS#2,
 STORE_OPEN_HOURS#3,
 STORE_OPEN_HOURS#4,
 STORE_OPEN_HOURS#5,
 STORE_OPEN_HOURS#6,
 STORE_OPEN_HOURS#7,
 STORE_CLOSE_HOURS#1,
 STORE_CLOSE_HOURS#2,
 STORE_CLOSE_HOURS#3,
 STORE_CLOSE_HOURS#4,
 STORE_CLOSE_HOURS#5,
 STORE_CLOSE_HOURS#6,
 STORE_CLOSE_HOURS#7,
 MAILING_ADDRESS,
 MAILING_CITY,
 MAILING_STATE,
 cast(MAIL_ZIP_PREFIX as numeric (5,0)) as MAIL_ZIP_PREFIX,
 cast(MAIL_ZIP_SUFFIX as numeric (4,0)) as MAIL_ZIP_SUFFIX,
 convert(datetime, CREATE_DATE) as CREATE_DATE,
 convert(datetime, GetDate()) as MODIFY_DATE,
 replace(Convert (varchar(8), GetDate(), 108),':','') as MODIFY_TIME,
 'DAILY UPDATE',
 AGENT_TYPE,
 NAIC_CODE,
 cast(CONTRACT_TYPE as numeric (1,0)) as CONTRACT_TYPE,
 LONGITUDE,
 LATITUDE,
 CORP_NAME,
 DSR,
 FEDTAX_NAME,
 FEDTAX_ID,
 TIN_TYPE,
 NAME_CONTROL,
 cast(ES_GROUPTYPE as numeric (6,0)) as ES_GROUPTYPE,
 ADDRESS2,
 --cast(CORPORATION_NUMBER as numeric (11,0)),
 convert(datetime, INSTALL_date)
from sdg_tmp_aaismain as tmp
where NOT EXISTS(select NULL
                 from sdg_aaismain as dest
                 where tmp.agent_number = dest.agent_number 
                 )
```

The above code is a sample of a longer update statement. I have 2 columns giving me the "Error converting data type varchar to numeric" error. This is because there is character data for some records.

The out of range error is occurring for 4 different varchar columns with dates which all have '00000000' as a value for some of the rows.

How do I go about excluding the character data and the zeroes from my select query?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: One of the columns I am having trouble with is CORPORATION_NUMBER. I tried adding the following code to my select statement  and get this error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
(select cast(tmp.CORPORATION_NUMBER as numeric (11,0)) as CORPORATION_NUMBER 
from sdg_tmp_aaismain tmp 
where tmp.CORPORATION_NUMBER not in ('','0','00000000000')
and tmp.CORPORATION_NUMBER not like '%[a-z,A-Z,/,\,-,.]%')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude the row entirely, then you can do:

```
WHERE ISDATE(someColumn)=1
```

If you want to include the row, but drive a null into the date you can do:

```
INSERT INTO someTable (datecolumn)
SELECT CASE WHEN ISDATE(someColumn)=1 THEN CONVERT(DATETIME,someColumn) ELSE NULL END
FROM someOtherTable
```

Comment: I tried this for CORPORATION _NUMBER at the end of my select statement using the following: (select case when CORPORATION_NUMBER not in ('','0','00000000000', 'nul') then convert(numeric, corporation_number) else null end from sdg_tmp_aaismain).....All of these columns allow NULLS. I am not sure why some of them have the string 'nul'. I still get the error converting varchar to numeric.

Comment: If you are doing numerics, you can do `isnumeric(somecolumn)=1` in place of `isdate(somecolumn)=1` rather that hard coding a list.